# How to save axis bounds in excel after running a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an excel project in which i have a chart having a y-axis and an x-axis.
I can see on excel that i can modify the format of the axis and choose the minimum scale and the maximum scale as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

My procedure is as follow:

Step 1: Run macro test1() that populates the data in the chart1 
Step 2: Look at chart1 and decide whether the minimum and maximum scale should be changed or not. 
If yes, change the values using excel's "Format Axis" in the picutre above. 
Step 3: Run one more time the same macro test1() (this step is mandatory)

However, after setting the axis values as wanted, when i run test1(), the values seem to be reset to their original value (discarded the value I entered manually for both axis)

Can anyone tell me how to ensure that excel will keep the values i entered as a minimum and a maximum scale even when i run a macro?

Thank you :)

Comment: If you know ahead of time what the desired values are, include them in the macro `myChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MIN` and `myChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MAX` (where `MIN` and `MAX` are the desired values)

Comment: I do not know what are the values i want to set up @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: ??? if you don't know what the values you want to setup are then how can you set them up before running your macro? There is either info missing somewhere or we are facing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please check update above @cybernetic.nomad
I hope this makes it more clear :)

Comment: Sounds like you need a `userform` or `inputbox` to capture your bounds (MIN and MAX), so they can be translated to your `test1`, where you would have within your code what @cybernetic.nomad listed in his first comment.  If you set `MIN` and `MAX` as global variables, you would be able to maintain those going forward, where you need a check to see if MIN and MAX will be utilized.

Comment: There is no way for excel to remember the values i insert as minimum and maximum scale? @Cyril

Comment: @CelineN yes you can; see the answer I listed.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on comment to explain where min/max would be checked.

```
Option Explicit
Public MIN as Long, MAX as Long
'
Public Sub CallUF()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

'Call test1 from the COmmandbutton in the UF
Private Sub test1()
    'run your other code then use this to format after the fact
    MIN = UserForm1.Textbox1.Value
    MAX = UserForm1.Textbox2.Value
    If MIN > 0 And MAX > 0 then
        myChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MIN 'copied from cybernetic's comment
        myChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MAX 'copied from cybernetic's comment
    End If
End Sub
```

`MIN` and `MAX` will be maintained and used for other graphs created using `test1`.

You could use a userform or inputbox to get the `MIN`/`MAX` values, and could run load the userform/inputbox at the start of the code so that you can either list `0` so it does its default effort, or use the values (which would be entered as known).

You may want to build some logic about when to pull the userform/inputbox, so that way you aren't overwriting them in the future (or you can have them populated with `MIN` and `MAX` when you initiate a userform).